# how to use @jvmoverloads with interface in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

My codebase is mixed java and kotlin code. I'd like to use @JvmOverloads on interface method with default arguments. Like that:

```
@JvmOverloads
fun getClientCompanyId(clientId: Long, date: DateTime = DateTime.now()): Long
```

I can't do this unfortunately and I get the message that:

> JvmOverloads cannot be used on interface methods

However if I use it on overridden function then I get

> Platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same JVM signature(getClientCompanyId(JLorg/joda/time/DateTime;)J):
>
> - @JvmOverloads public open fun getClientCompanyId(clientId: Long, date: DateTime = ...): Long
> - @JvmOverloads public open fun getClientCompanyId(clientId: Long, date: DateTime = ...): Long

and just for the record: when I try to put default value in overridden method I get the message that:

> An overriding function is not allowed to specify default values on its parameters

Is it a possible thing to do in kotlin? Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: I encountered the same problem, have you ever found a better solution?

Comment: as far as I know, there isn't one

Comment: [KT-36102: Allow @JvmOverloads in interfaces](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-36102)

Answer (score 16):

I believe the best you can do is to define the overloads yourself. e.g.:

```
fun getClientCompanyId(clientId: Long, date: DateTime): Long
fun getClientCompanyId(clientId: Long) = getClientCompanyId(clientId, DateTime.now())
```

Comment: Thanks mate, but obviously I already did that and was trying to improve it.

Comment: I understand you were hoping for a better/different answer. If you want to discuss adding features to the language to improve this I recommend posting on discuss.kotlinlang.org.

Answer (score 2):

Spoilers ahead: This answer is not satisfying.

I ran into a similar issue while converting a Java class and interface into kotlin. The only way that my legacy Java code accepts `@JvmOverloads` generated code was to change my kotlin `interface` into an `open class` and change all `fun()` into `open fun()`

Works but its not what we really want.